# ArcMap vertex problem for Z-value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, 3d, oracle-spatial

I have an Oracle Spatial dataset with z-coords. I can edit the dataset in ArcMap however the z-values are always rounded to the nearest integer.

Why does ArcMap round the z-values?

Comment: Are you sure that they are indeed being rounded or maybe you have it set to display no decimal places?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The sketch dialog box shows the z-values with decimals. As soon as I change any z-value all the z-coords are rounded.

Comment: Please check the spatial reference for the z tolerance and resolution values. Also check the editing snap tolerance value.